# Vector Autoregressive Model with Exogenous Inputs and Lasso Penalty

Tags: r

i am wondering if anyone is aware of a package that would allow me to do vector autoregression with exogenous variables (similar to the VARMAX procedure in SAS)?  I have looked around and found the fastVAR package but it is no longer available.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Have you look looked at [dse: Dynamic Systems Estimation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dse/index.html)? In addition to the standard ARMA model it supports VAR and VARX analysis. Also, while no longer available on CRAN, you can install the fastVAR package from [GitHub](https://github.com/jeffwong/fastVAR):

```
install.packages('devtools')
library('devtools')
install_github('fastVAR', user='jeffwong')
```

The maintainer says it is just a test version and not in a release state. A trial install on OS X 10.9.1 with R 3.0.2 and Rcpp 0.11.0 fails.